# How can I change the Aspect ratio & Size of pictures in Powerpoint 2010 in all slides?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I need to make power point presentation for my work. I want to automatically change the pictures of different slides.

I want to change aspect ratio, size and alignment of all the pictures of slides according to the picture "First Slide"

[image]

Comment: See if this helps... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-size-of-your-slides-040a811c-be43-40b9-8d04-0de5ed79987e

Comment: The easiest way (though it's not automatically) is to create a layout in Master Slide view with image and text placeholders. Then add your image on each slide, according to the position and size of your placeholder. BTW... there are so many wires on that post.